# Where does Derrida say that deconstruction and the existence of or belief in God are incompatible?

Tags: theology, continental-philosophy, heidegger, derrida, deconstruction

I am searching for a text I've since lost that I believe is a transcription of a conversation between someone and Derrida. The context may have been Heidegger's particular conception of philosophy and its incompatibility with the existence of / belief in God. I remember it as a lengthy quote.

Comment: Could be *Violence and Metaphysics* as part of his critique of Levinas. Though I'm thinking that there it will be more about ontotheology and the term God (thus the reference to existence).

Comment: Unfortunately I clearly remember that it was an interview where Derrida referenced Heidegger but made a general statement saying that philosophy, or maybe deconstruction, and the belief in a God are irreconcilable and incompatible.

Comment: problematic comments dealt with. They have, as far as I can tell, absolutely nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall Derrida making that statement but the discussion of Augustine, Heidegger, Destruction/Deconstruction, and prayer comes up in Circumfession.  Maybe this is what you are looking for:  http://www.ubu.com/sound/derrida.html